# IBM worklight HttpAdapter throwing UNRESPONSIVE_HOST Error

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, mobilefirst-adapters

When I check adapter in preview mode it works fine in both mobile browser and web browser.

when I call the same procedure from mobile app, It throws the following error.

> {"invocationContext":null,"errorCode":"UNRESPONSIVE_HOST","errorMsg":"The service is currently not available."}

Comment: Is your application configured to connect the server?

Comment: did  you move adapter production server ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that the application is pointing to your server:

1. I don't know what do you mean by "mobile app" (Android app or iOS app or previewing the mobileweb environment from the mobile browser in the device), but make sure that the host IP address in the worklight.plist/wlclient.properties is the correct one (not "localhost", but an IP address).
2. Ensure that in the adapter XML you are not using "localhost" as well.